# why intersection is empty?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$U_n=(n,+\infty)$, then the intersection is empty

Im not getting why intersection is empty ?

Suppose im taking $U_1 = ( 1, \infty)$ and $U_2 = ( 2, \infty)$ now $U_1 \cap U_2= (1, \infty) \cap ( 2, \infty) = (2, \infty) \neq  \emptyset$

Comment: $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}(n,\infty)$ is empty due to the Archimedean property of the real numbers.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  but  the  archimedean properties  used in  $\mathbb{N}$      and my question is  different    im talking in open interval

Comment: there is no $x\in\mathbb R $ that is in $(n,\infty)$ for all $n$

Comment: @jasmine So what actually is your question then?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown $ ( n , \infty)$ is an open interval

Comment: @jasmine That's not a question $\ddot\frown$

Comment: The confusion is due to the ambiguity in "the intersection is empty": _what_ intersection are you talking about? Yes,  $Q_1\cap Q_2\ne\emptyset$, but here "the intersection"  refers to $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty Q_n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They mean that

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U_n = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (n, + \infty) = \emptyset$$

which is obvious, because if an element $x$ is in this intersection, then $x > n$ for all $n \geq 1$ and no real number has this property.

Answer (score 2):

If $U_n=(n,\infty)$ then $A=\bigcap\limits_{n\in \mathbb Z^+}U_n=\emptyset$.

Suppose otherwise that $A \not=\emptyset$ then there is some $x\in A$ which means $\forall n, x\in U_n=(n,\infty)$. So $\forall n,x\gt n$. which is a contradiction since $\mathbb Z^+$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 2):

The intersection $I_n$ of any *finite* number $n$ of these sets is certainly not empty, since

$$I_n= \bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{n}(k,\infty) = (n,\infty)$$

Note that as $n$ increases, the intersection $I_n$ shrinks: $$I_1\supset I_2 \supset I_3\supset\cdots \supset I_n\supset I_{n+1}\cdots$$

This in itself doesn't necessarily mean that the intersection $I_{\infty}$ of all the sets is empty. However, for this particular set of intervals, no point $x>0$ can be in $I_{\infty}$ because in fact for any given $x>0$ there is an $n$ such that the finite intersection $I_n$ has already "escaped" $x$. Specifically, given $x$, put $n = \lceil x\rceil $ (the smallest integer greater than $x$). Then $x\notin I_n$, so certainly $x\notin I_{\infty}$.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the statement was meant to be that the intersection of all $U_n$ is empty.

The intersection of all $U_n$ would be the set of real numbers that are greater than any natural number, and obviously no number satisfies this.

Answer (score 1):

$(1,+\infty) \cap (2,+\infty) \cap (3,+\infty) \cap \cdots = \varnothing$.

Maybe those other answers using $\displaystyle \bigcap$ are confusing you.